# Windows 8 tries to log into my user account at startup

Tags: windows, windows-8

Every time I start Windows 8, it tries to log into my user account (Microsoft account).

The computer has an e-mail account with company rules. This is the only thing I changed.

This keeps the computer busy for ~4 minutes. How can I change this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download [AutoLogon from Sysinternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963905.aspx), start it with admin rights (rightclick and select "Run as administrator") and click on the disable button. Now Windows no longer tries to autologon your Account when you start the PC.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use the built-in Regedit
Navigate to:

```
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\winlogon
```

Set: AutoAdminLogon = 0 (one means automatic, zero means off, normal logon.)

Here is more information I wrote on the topic of
[Regedit and Auto Logon in Windows 8](http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/win8/windows8-autoadminlogon-registry.htm)